# How can i prevent my Galaxy Note 4 from detecting tethering when I enable USB debuggin?

Tags: android

I have a galaxy Note 4 that I want to connect to my computer via USB cable.  Whenever I activate USB debugging I get a message telling me that my phone has detected tethering and USB debug mode is automatically turned off.  I'm not trying to share my phones internet connection with my desktop, I just want to be able to transfer data from the phone's storage.  I don't want to pay an extra fee just because my phone thinks I'm trying to share my internet connection.  My carrier is US Cellular.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue on huawei p9.
to solve the problem:

1. press "restoring default settings" if it exist(in huawei it's exist)
2. enter developer mode setting
3. enable "OEM unlocking"
4. now, enable USB Debugging - it should work.